# Using Maven to install Bower components with Bower installed globally

Tags: java, maven, bower, exec-maven-plugin

I have bower installed globally using NPM. 
In my Maven project I have a bower.json file, I am using the exec-maven-plugin to install the bower components on build, however it failed because it "cannot run the program 'bower' in directory" which makes sense because Bower is not locally installed in the project directory.

However I want to use the global version of Bower so I don't have separate Bower programs in all my projects, it works if I go to the directory in terminal and manual run 'bower install'.

Question: I want Maven to use my global Bower version to avoid me having duplicate copies of Bower in each project, how do I do this?

This is the code from my POM file that runs the plugin and execution:

```
 <plugin>

  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>

  <executions>

    <execution>
      <id>exec-bower-install</id>

      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>

        <executable>bower</executable>

        <arguments>
          <argument>install</argument>
        </arguments>

      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>

  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of testing, I've figured out it was a problem with my IDE, for some reason Netbeans gives me an error when it tries to build the project during the plugin execution, however when I run the Maven project straight from command line, it builds!

Answer (score 2):

don't forget the **workingDirectory** and put your bower.json inside root folder

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
     <execution>
     <phase>generate-sources</phase>
     <goals>
      <goal>exec</goal>
     </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
     <executable>bower</executable>
     <arguments>
      <argument>install</argument>
     </arguments>
     <workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I'm no getting this error: `env: node: No such file or directory` which is to do with node configurations... (i'm guessing) however I have node installed globally as is bower, but i'm not even using node so why does it matter?

Comment: Note: `bower.json` has to be inside `${basedir}/src/main/webapp`.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the **executable property** to point to the full directory of the bower executable, for example:

```
 <executable>c:/bower_directory/bower</executable>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I've tried using:   `<executable>/Mavericks/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower</executable>` which gives me _Command execution failed. Cannot run program "/Mavericks/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower"_ and `<executable>/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower</executable> `which gives me _Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 127_, however if I go to terminal and run `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower` the usual bower message shows