# How to run a maven webapp with bower in eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, bower, bower-install

I am trying integrate bower in my maven webapp here is my pom.xml and and bower.json but i was failed to download the dependencies. this here is my pom.xml and bower.json files.And one more question does i need the nodejs or npm help to download the dependencies ?

bower.json:

```
{
"name": "Bower1",
"version": "1.0.0",

"description": "javaee7-angular JavaScript dependencies.",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.0",
    "jquery": "1.9.1",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.10.0",
    "angular-grid": "2.0.7"
}
```

}

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>

    <finalName>Bower1</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>bower</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>install</argument>
                </arguments>
                <workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Maven to install Bower components with Bower installed globally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27822050/using-maven-to-install-bower-components-with-bower-installed-globally)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @zillani but while installing the bower i am getting the error like "'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." how can i resolve this.???

Comment: np, find my answer below, let me know if it helps @Gopi Krishna Seeram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Step by step process to run bower in a maven eclipse project:

1.install npm in your local system

2.Add the following plug  in your maven `pom.xml` `<build></build>` tags

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bower install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bower</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>
```

3.Add the following `bower.json` file in your `webapp` root folder

```
 {
"name": "BowerTest",
"version": "1.0.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.0",
    "jquery": "1.9.1",
    "bootstrap":"3.3.7",
    "css":""
}}
```

4. If you want to add any dependencies add your dependency within `dependencies` as shown above `bower.json` file.

5. Then right click on your project click on `bower install` after this installation one folder will be created like `bower_components` in your root path there you can found your dependencies then refer that dependencies into your view layer.

Answer (score 0):

Bower needs npm (node package manager), so install npm and make sure its on your PATH, [image]

npm download: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: @zillani...Yup i am having npm but still while running that application in eclipse i am getting the same error.So,please tell me the overall flow to work with the bower in a maven webapp.

Comment: @GopiKrishnaSeeram as you mentioned, you see the error, node' is not recognized as an internal or external command. did you give node -v and see the version ?

Comment: my current node version is v6.9.5